# unable to access neo4j and node.js from android phone on server with global ip (non local host or non 192.168.X.X)?

Tags: android, node.js, neo4j, database-connectivity

i want to connect  to my server running on global ip '117.195.72.170' port 6060 from other than local network ie over internet. I am running my app on android phone and the server has node.JS (port 9090)server and Neo4j (port 7474 ) Database. please guide me to the steps where i  use the proper port and get successful connection. thanks

Comment: I am able to access neo4-j and node server in local network and app works correctly. but not with global ip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the appropriate person in your IT department to open up the desired port on that IP address.